# Test for three callouts in one Queueable class

Tags: unit-test, callout

I have 2 callouts in one class. I use XML mock in static resources.
How to provide the right fake XML to every callout?

Thank you

````
public with sharing class x implements Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    private String sessionID;
    private String recordID;

    public x(String sessionID, String recordID) {
        this.sessionID = sessionID;
        this.recordID = recordID;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context) {

    String **calloutresponse1** = PI0Helper.retrieveTimePointsForOccasionInclEOS(sessionID, dataRecord.Scr_ID, 'test1, test2');

    //parse calloutresponse1 and update Record 1

    String **calloutresponse2** = String calloutresponse1 = PI0Helper.retrieveTimePointsForOccasionInclEOS(sessionID, **Parsedidfrom1**, 'test3, test4');

    //parse calloutresponse2 and update Record 2

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
@isTest
private class CalloutMultiStaticClassTest {
    @isTest static void testCalloutWithMultipleStaticResources() {
    // Use MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock to
    // specify fake response for a certain endpoint and 
    // include response body in a static resource.    
    MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock multimock = new MultiStaticResourceCalloutMock();
    multimock.setStaticResource(
        'http://example.com/example/test', 'mockResponse'); // mockResponse is a static resource file with mock response
    multimock.setStaticResource(
        'http://example.com/example/sfdc', 'mockResponse2'); // mockResponse2 is a static resource file with mock response
    multimock.setStatusCode(200);
    multimock.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    
    // Set the mock callout mode
    Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, multimock);
    
    // Call the method for the first endpoint
    HTTPResponse res = CalloutMultiStaticClass.getInfoFromExternalService(
        'http://example.com/example/test');
    // Verify response received 
    System.assertEquals('{"hah":"fooled you"}', res.getBody());
    
    // Call the method for the second endpoint
    HTTPResponse res2 = CalloutMultiStaticClass.getInfoFromExternalService(
        'http://example.com/example/sfdc');
    // Verify response received 
    System.assertEquals('{"hah":"fooled you twice"}', res2.getBody());
  }
}
```

Comment: this only works if each callout goes to a different endpoint; you need a different approach using a counter if multiple callouts go to the same endpoint